# Word for the back side of a letter

Tags: terminology

The back side of a coin is called *[reverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obverse_and_reverse)*, the left or back side of a bound manuscript is the *[verso](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recto_and_verso)*, but what is the back of a piece of paper such as a letter (not the envelope) called? Dictionaries give a wide selection of options (rear, back, reverse, backside, flipside, back page, etc.), and I don't understand which of these a native speaker would most likely use here.

I would like to direct the reader of a formal letter (which in this case is a legal document) to further information on its back, e.g. "bla bla (see the back of this letter)".

Comment: I think “back”  is the more common term.

Comment: You could call it the "verso" and confuse everyone but the typesetting community.

Comment: "Reverse" seems fine. Other terms like "other side" or "overleaf" technically could mean the front if you were already looking at the back, but such pedantry doesn't help.

Comment: @StuartF Thank you. In this case the reference is from the front to the back as explained in the body of my question (last sentence).

Comment: @user888379 As the letter is for the U.S. Customs and Border Protection and my permission to enter the United States hinges on it, I don't want to be clever.

Comment: @user52445 That's good judgment on your part. You can save "verso" for a purely social occasion.

Comment: *For bla bla, see reverse.* (or just: *See reverse*)

Answer (score 2):

"bla bla (see the back of this letter)" -> *"bla bla (see overleaf)"* Collins Concise English Dictionary © HarperCollins Publishers:: **overleaf** /ˌəʊvəˈliːf/ adv *on the other side of the page*.

Comment: *overleaf* means *on the other side* — not *the other side*.

Comment: @TinfoilHat I did a [Google Books search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22see+overleaf%22&lr=lang_en&tbs=lr:lang_1en&tbm=bks&tbas=0&source=lnt&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjK4Jj5n6v_AhWXgf0HHeb6CvUQpwV6BAgKECY&biw=1470&bih=834&dpr=2) for the phrase "see overleaf" and it seems to be used quite commonly to point readers to the back side of the preset page. What is your objection?

Comment: @user52445 I suppose TinfoilHat is pointing out that you can't use "overleaf" to mean the back of a piece of paper in isolation - if you said "look at the overleaf" it would mean nothing, you have to write "see overleaf" on the front of a piece of paper for it to refer to the back of that same piece.

Comment: @TinfoilHat *overleaf means* on the other side — not *the other side.* Yes... that is what I quoted - it's an adverb... which is pointed out.

Comment: We don’t *\*see on the other side* — we *see the other side*. (*overleaf* is a  book publishing term, usually used to caption something that fills the whole next spread, e.g.: *Overleaf: Hoover Dam in 1937*)

Comment: PS, @user52445 : Don’t use *overleaf* on your letter to the U.S. Customs and Border Protection. Even if it will be understood, it is not idiomatic.

Comment: @TinfoilHat - not in the UK, where it is commonly used within the body of a letter, report, etc. "London's Contemporary Architecture: An Explorer's Guide" 2014 *64B Aquatics venue (see overleaf), designed by Zaha Hadid* -- "Virgin to Veteran: How to Get Cooking with Confidence" 2013 *... store—bought or homemade (see overleaf) MARINADE 1½ teaspoons red harissa paste*

Comment: Those are both books, not letters or reports. [And both of them use *overleaf* inconsistently](https://www.google.com/books/edition/London_s_Contemporary_Architecture/HuHpAwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=overleaf): *(see overleaf)*; *(illustrated in this column and overleaf)*. Lastly: in any case, OP is wishing to communicate with the United States.